# In-built way to display browser specific "popups blocked" icon in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing an application that can open a new window. Obviously some browsers will prevent this and add a "popups blocked" icon to the address bar and display a message. My application is designed for less technologically inclined individuals, so in the event they choose to open the new window, I want a message will appear explaining they need to allow popups, by clicking on the "popups blocked" icon.

I am wondering if there is some way in HTML to access the icon, or if it will be necessary to just store several images of each brower's icon and determine the browser to display the relevant icon.

Apologies if the question is rather easy, searching online was difficult as I am unsure as to the exact terms these browser specific icons would go under.

Comment: down-voter please comment.... I think This is a valid question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store several images of the specific browser pop-up-blocked icons and determine which image you gotta show

Comment: Bummer. Thanks for the answer though. I'd upvote but too new.